# Internet connection slow on one machine but not others

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet

Apologies if this has been asked but I can't seem to figure out what the heck is going on and the exact situation I'm in is a bit too complicated to search on Google (I've tried).

To be as quick as possible, I'm reaching speeds of 120+Mbps on all of my wireless devices and 100Mbps on my router, however my desktop (which is also wired in) is getting 20-40Mbps at best. Now here's the strange part. Using iperf3 I was easily able to get speeds to other devices on my LAN of 500-900Mbps depending on whether one was wireless and how far it was. I really can't understand this whatsoever.

Really hoping this problem isn't too specific for here.

Comment: You sure that's not a disk issue?

Comment: I'm very sure. I'm using a Sabrent Rocket 4.0 NVMe SSD that's currently in perfect health.